# Se eu sinalizar uma resposta e a pessoa editar?

Tags: suporte

Por exemplo eu sinalizei uma resposta assim:

> Você poderia dar mais detalhes?

Isso deveria estar nos comentários e não como resposta. A sinalização foi que "não é uma resposta". Porém a pessoa editou e colocou realmente uma resposta correta no lugar.

Se eu sinalizar uma resposta e a pessoa editar essa mesma resposta, como será visualizado [para o analista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review)? Desaparecerá a "sinalização"?

Comment: "*Por exemplo eu sinalizei uma resposta assim*" - Você quis dizer "*Por exemplo, eu **postei um comentário em** uma resposta assim*"?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Acho que ele quis dizer: "A resposta que sinalizei era assim", mas foi uma sinalização padrão, tb fiquei confuso a princípio

Comment: Não tenho certeza, pode ser que a flag seja macada como útil ou que ela continue lá e se for rejeitada o sistema marca como disputed. Tenho que verificar.

Comment: Pela minha experiencia, nada acontece de diferente. Se você sinaliza um post, e o OP o edita após isso, ela vai pra fila normalmente. Cabe ao analista estar atento na hora da analise.

Comment: Não sem responder. Mas imagino que seja exibida a versão da pergunta atual, e quem analisa ignore a sinalização, já que a sinalização não faz sentido e ter uma sinalização ignorada não penaliza ninguém(Até onde sei).